# Dark and black colors on screen have fuzzy 'noise'

Tags: nvidia, graphics, screen

The closest thing to this problem I can find is [Fuzzy static noise on screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219060/fuzzy-static-noise-on-screen), but that is not the same problem I am having.

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 on an Asus G750JW laptop. I have installed the latest NVIDIA drivers from their website (346.59). Graphics acceleration is working perfectly.

Black or dark colors on the screen are 'noisey'. It looks something like [this](http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/black_noise-t2.jpg), but darker.

Edit: Forgot to mention this does not happen on Windows.

It's not extremely annoying, but I would like to get it fixed. My graphics card is a Nvidia 765M. Any ideas?

Comment: Is Dethering enabled in Nvidia x server settings? If yes what mode and depth?

Comment: Where can I find it? Here's my x11 config: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10855949/

Comment: When you install Nvidia driver it installs the settings software too. Search Nvidia in ubuntu and it should show up.

Comment: I know; the Nvidia X Server settings application. I just don't know where to look!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/602260/pixelated-wallpaper-background/604678#604678 take a look there, not sure if it will help.

Comment: Thanks; setting Dithering to disabled fixed the problem!

Comment: Good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Same here. After playing a little with *Dithering* options **the noise is gone**!
Thanks to Maiwand for the clue! )

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/528852)

Comment: @ByteCommander This is the only answer, so it can't be a thank you answer..

Comment: @Seth Actually it is a thanks answer thanking for the solution in the comments... That question was long solved, but nobody bothered to write an answer with the correct solution. Yes, I missed that due to the review queue's focus. But I am still not too sure what should happen with this?

Comment: @byte nothing needs to happen. But upvoting it would mark the question solved.